# Gherkin Syntax - What do Uptick and Dollar symbols signify?

Tags: gherkin, acceptance-testing

I am ramping up my working knowledge of Gherkin and while the whole process is clear - I am seeing two DIFFERENT version of Gherkin syntaxes.

```
Given I bought two apples
  And I bought two oranges
Then I have 10 euros left
```

vs

```
Given ^I bought two apples$
  And ^I bought two oranges$
Then ^I have 10 euros left$
```

I have tried to find what the latter  (Containing `^` and `$`) signifies and how is it different from the former. I've seen examples of both on the net but I dont understand the difference between the two or when to use which. Could someone help point out what these differences are and when to apply which sytax?

Answer (score 1):

^ and $ are regular expression wildcards,  where ^ stands for the start of the line, $ is the end of the line.
It looks like they are used in some particular implementation of the Gherkin step definitions.
They are not part of standard Gherkin. The first syntax is valid.